# Как преобразовать массив с одинаковыми ключами в ассоциативный, сохраняя все значения?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

У меня есть сущность edu в БД , куда складываются все статьи обучающихся. В статьи они грузят файлы. Под файлы есть отдельная сущность files (там хранится путь к файлу, к какой статье он относится и владелец файла). Подразумевается, что в статье может быть больше 1 файла.
При запросе я получаю такую выборку (см.скрин1)
[image: Выборка из БД]

Все, кроме путя к файлу одинаковое т.к. принадлежит одной статье. По этой выборке я хочу получить ассоциативный массив в php для вывода в статью всех файлов, принадлежащих этой статье. Однако при слиянии двух строк из выборки в ассоциативный массив с помощью

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,$string);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

На выходе я получаю это (см.скрин2) - Только первую строку выборки. Как это можно обойти? Без считывания mysqli_fetch_row
[image: Ассоциативный массив, который получает php]

Comment: а где у вас слияние двух строк? чтобы сделать массив строк, нужно пробежаться циклом по `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. в документации и в любом примере в интернете это есть

Comment: вариант для бедных - group_concat()

Answer (score -1):

ArchDemon@ верно подсказал, что я забыл сделать перебор.

Сделал так:

```php
for ($data = array (); $row = $query->fetch_assoc(); $data[] = $row);
```

в $data теперь хранятся элементы по типу
$data[0]['note']
$data[1]['summary']

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Этот код и сам по себе кривой, а главное не решает поставленную проблему